# Need to override exception class in java to get the exception message

Tags: java, selenium

I call an external function which, if results in an exception, prints only a part of the exception message.

Is there a way to capture the exception (maybe override the exception ?) and access the stack trace of the exception ? This is required as the stack trace would help in the further debugging.

I am using selenium with Java

Comment: If the exception is catch and not thrown again, you won't be able to get the exception instance. And if you are not the one throwing the exception, you can't use a specific type. So overriding the exception class would not help. Can you provide more information about the class and method visibility. Are they final ?

Comment: For example I have a function called settext ( it will set a value in the screen for a provided webelement) ,currently the settext if the element is not present ,it throws an exception and the exception is handled within the function and a part of the exception is printed in console . I need to capture the full exception so that I can see the root cause like in which line of the caller script it failed and so on ( attaching the msg thrown )